# Removing Babel from project? (React, Parceljs)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, parcel

I'm struggling with correctly configuring Babel in my React and Parceljs project. Right now, all I'm trying to do is completely remove babel from my project to start again with a clean slate. I've gone ahead and 'npm remove'-ed babel, as well as deleted my node.modules and package.lock.json.

This is my package.json currently.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel public/index.html",
    "start": "parcel public/index.html",
    "prod": "parcel build public/index.html"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  }
}
```

However when running 'npm install' again, the babel files reappear and in my package.lock.json and node_modules.

And I'm still getting these errors that only appeared once I started install @babel packages.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
...
×  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
...
```

Comment: Do you get warnings when you run `npm install`? Seems like either react or parcel are internally depending on babel

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. No.

Answer (score 1):

Parcel has been keeping a cache directory. Removing that and rebuilding fixed the problem.